# Warning narrowing conversion (uint32 to uint8)

Tags: c++

i have this warning. Can u help me ?

```
warning: narrowing conversion of ‘action’ from ‘uint32 {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘uint8 {aka unsigned char}’
```

How to convert uint32 to uint8 securely ?

Thanks

Comment: A snippet of related code would really help us to understand if you are trying to do the safe thing and compiler is just extra cautious, or if you are really doing dangerous stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is correct, such a conversion is potentially dangerous (it loses 24 higher bits).

You can tell the compiler that you really want this [unsafe] conversion by using explicit cast:

```
uint8_t my_byte_var = static_cast<uint8_t>(my_int32_var);
```

This should suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The narrowing warning/error should only arise if you use list-initialization, e.g.:

```
uint32_t action = 12345;
uint8_t val{action};
```

You could instead just use normal assignment:

```
uint8_t val = action;
```

The narrowing is still going to happen though, as there is no way for `12345` to fit in a `uint8_t`, so you'll be left with 9. If you're OK with that, then there's your solution. If not, then it's a good thing there's a warning because you're using the wrong type!

Comment: Depending on compiler options (for example `gcc -Wconversion`), you could get a warning on a simple assignment.